# How to use a controller inside another controller in Laravel5 as service

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have an Invoice controller it looks something like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Event;
use App\Employee;
use App\Invoice;
use Mail;
use View;

class ViewinvoiceController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function getIndex($order_id)
    {
       $id=$order_id;

        $invoicedata=Invoice::where('Id',$id)->get();


    $html22 =  View('viewinvoice')->with(array('invoicedata'=>$invoicedata ))->render();

     require_once(app_path().'/libs/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');


      $html2pdf = new \HTML2PDF('P','A4','en',true,'UTF-8',array(0, 0, 0, 0));

      // $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

      $html2pdf->WriteHTML($html22);

     $html2pdf->Output('Invoice.pdf');


    }

}
```

I want to use this controller in other controller which looks like this

```
class CollectionController extends Controller
    {

        public function __construct(){

    $this->middleware('role:collector'); // replace 'collector' with whatever role you need.
      }
       public function getInvoice($order_id){
       //Here I have to write the logic of getting the invoice from the invoiceController 
}

}
```

I googled and found out one way is to write a service to get invoice ,

I can make it as a normal class as service but I don't know whats the right way in laravel 5

Any suggestion

Comment: Controller's class name has same name as file name. So you will have to use two different controller file to handle different controllers.

Comment: @AjitKumarSingh can you please elaborate more on this , Actually in Laravel using a controller in another controller directly is not the right way since it opens way for `Injection` , I read some where using the php 5.+ `Trait` class we can do that or we can write a service in Laravel but I don't know any of them how to implement

Comment: This is what happens, when you call a controller, route.php is checked, if a controller exist. If it does, then the file having same name as invoked controller name is invoked. Your controller's class name, and file name should be same, to be invoked. However if you want to use another class, you will have to create the object of other class, in main class(But this is in java. I have not used it in php, so no idea).

Comment: @AjitKumarSingh I know in core PHP also I create an object of the class that I want to use in other class but if you take the concept of controllers , One controller should not talk to each other for that we should use something else in L5 which I yet to find out

Comment: Why do you want to talk to another controller?

Comment: If you create service then you can use it within your view files using `inject` while if you use traits you can simply use that trait within your class only. So what you need to use over here

Comment: @Uchiha so basically I want to use the viewInvoiceController in different  controller , The viewInvoice creates a PDF in invoice form , so I want to use it with other controllers , Like collection , admin etc . What do you suggest I should do here

Comment: Simply create a trait file and use it within your controller

Comment: @Uchiha can you please give me an example how I can do it , I went to php trait documentation but was not able to understand properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place this trait within your `App\Services` and save the file with name `ViewinvoiceTrait.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Services;

use App\Invoice;
use View;

trait ViewinvoiceTrait {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function getIndex($order_id) {
        $id = $order_id;

        $invoicedata = Invoice::where('Id', $id)->get();


        $html22 = View('viewinvoice')->with(array('invoicedata' => $invoicedata))->render();

        require_once(app_path() . '/libs/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');


        $html2pdf = new \HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en', true, 'UTF-8', array(0, 0, 0, 0));

        // $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

        $html2pdf->WriteHTML($html22);

        return $html2pdf->Output('Invoice.pdf');
    }

}
```

and use this within your Controller like as

```
use App\Services\ViewinvoiceTrait;

class CollectionController extends Controller
    {

     use ViewinvoiceTrait;

     public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('role:collector'); // replace 'collector' with whatever role you need.
     }

     public function getInvoice($order_id){
          $data = $this->getIndex($order_id);
     }

}
```

Comment: @Uchicha do I need to register the service in the config/app/php ?/\

Answer (score 0):

Using Controller inside another Controller as against the design standard, if you think you have some functionality that needs to be triggered in several Controllers or locations, here comes the `Jobs`.

Read more about Laravel Jobs [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues). Jobs can run synchronously or asynchronously, this is up to your application.